# Second router not outputting right speeds

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have a 200 up and 200 down meg fibre line that I have setted up in the main house. I connected a second router in my flat and only get 100 up and down. The cables are catE6 that I used to connect the routers and the second router can take up to 600 meg dowbload so it could not be that.

Please help me I cannot figure on what is wrong. If I cannot find a fix I will have to downgrade

Comment: " I connected a second router in my flat"  <-- What is the distance?  If long, is it properly run?   Did you make your own ends?

Comment: Does the router support 1000Mbits? Or maybe it is just 100Mbits?

Comment: @John the distance is 10 meters and I bought the wire from my service provider. If I test it at the original router I get the right speeds but at the second router is when I get the reduced speeds

Comment: Try updating the firmware in the second router (as you eliminated other variables). If possible, try a different second router.

Comment: This question is compiling close votes, please add additional information to the question. At the very least, you should add the make/model numbers of the devices...